# Get value back from a text box class

Tags: forms, powershell, textbox

We have a script that was written by someone who is no longer with us. I am new to `powershell` and this function is not returning a value:

```
# prompt user for ip/dns address input.
Function get-ip
{
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

# Creates a message box that accepts dns/ip address input.
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text = "User Input Required"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,40) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please enter the IP address of the server you want to connect to:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,70) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
}
```

I'm calling it as such:

```
$ip = get-ip
```

I enter in a value and I'm not getting anything in the `$ip`.

How do I capture the value of a text box?

**FOR MARTIN**

I made the changes that Martin suggested and here is my new code:

```
# prompt user for ip/dns address input.
Function get-ip
{
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

# Creates a message box that accepts dns/ip address input.
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text = "User Input Required"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$script:x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$script:x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,40) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please enter the IP address of the server you want to connect to:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,70) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
$x
}
```

I get the same error message as before:

```
PS E:\Dropbox\Powershell Scripts\SSS Cloud Icons> .\cloudicons.ps1
Creating Directories...
mkdir : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At E:\Dropbox\Powershell Scripts\SSS Cloud Icons\cloudicons.ps1:80 char:4
+ md $_.userName
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [mkdir], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,mkdir
```

Did I miss something?

** UPDATE **

I was asked how I was calling get-ip:

```
# Insert user entered IP into pipeline.
$ip = get-ip
# Sets user entered IP into new file called propanehasip.rdp.
(get-content .\propanetest.rdp) -replace 'full address:s:INSERTIPHERE',"full address:s:$ip" | Out-File propanehasip.rdp

Write-Host "Creating Directories..."
Import-Csv $csv | ForEach-Object { 
# Creates directories based on the userName field.
md $_.userName
# Creates icons based on propanehasip.rdp and WSID fields.
(get-content ".\propanehasip.rdp") -replace 'remoteapplicationcmdline:s:INSERTWSIDHERE',"remoteapplicationcmdline:s:$($_.wsid1)" | out-file ".\$($_.username)\Propane $($_.wsid1).rdp"
(get-content ".\propanehasip.rdp") -replace 'remoteapplicationcmdline:s:INSERTWSIDHERE',"remoteapplicationcmdline:s:$($_.wsid2)" | out-file ".\$($_.username)\Propane $($_.wsid2).rdp"
}
}
```

**UPDATE #2**

I figured out how to debug this in visual studio. The error is happening on this line:

(get-content .\propanetest.rdp) -replace 'full address:s:INSERTIPHERE',"full address:s:$ip" | Out-File propanehasip_new.rdp

Comment: Your second function with Martins update returns a value for me. The error seems unrelated to the `get-ip` function... where are you calling `md $_.userName`?

Comment: @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF Thanks for the reply. I have added an update to the question to answer yours.

Comment: Try adding a condition before `md` to check userName is not an empty string: `Import-Csv $csv | ? { $_.userName } | ForEach-Object {...`

Comment: Am I adding the closing bracket after the }} at the end? If so, I got numerous errors when it tried to loop quite a few times.

Comment: Ok, I debugged it and it's happening on the line I stated above.

Comment: Paste your code into an editor with syntax highlighting. It can show you, which brackets are assigned to each othe { ... } and if you are missing some.
Can you check, if the directories with the usernames got created?
From your script you can use test-path.

Comment: To get back to your errormessage: "mkdir : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string." - can you check that your csv contains a Header named username and is not empty? The error states, that $_.username is empty, and so the Directory could not be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x is only valid inside the block (the scope of variable $x), if you change it to $script:x and add an $x before the ending } of your function, then it works.
The additional $x is needed to represent the return value of your function.

Changes:

```
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$script:x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$script:x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
```

End of function:

```
$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
$x
}
```

And... this script is taken from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx) and should demonstrate the use of Windows.Forms. However, i didnt found the date, when it was posted.

Comment: ty for your response. I added details of what I did in the original post.

Comment: Nice catch. `Set-Variable -Scope 1 -Name x` would be safer though